# Can't get partykit package's mob function to do univariate MLE fit

Tags: r, oop, party

I can't get the partykit package's mob function to do univariate MLE fit.

```
# Trying to convert vignette example here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/mob.pdf on page 7 to do univariate MLE gamma fits.  
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes", package = "mlbench")    
library("partykit")     
library("fitdistrplus")    


# Generating some fake data to replace the example data.
op <- options(digits = 3)
set.seed(123)    
x <- rgamma(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes), shape = 5, rate = 0.1)
PimaIndiansDiabetes$diabetes<-x
PimaIndiansDiabetes$glucose<-x 

#Hopefully this change to the formula means fit a gamma to just the diabetes vector of values!
pid_formula <- diabetes  ~ 1  | pregnant + pressure + triceps + insulin + mass + pedigree + age    

#Defining my own, negative of log likelihood since mob will minimize it.    
estfun<-function(z) {-logLik(z)} 

#replacing the call to glm that is successful in the vignette example.    
class(fitdistr) <- append(class(fitdistr),estfun)              
logit <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {
         fitdistr(y, "gamma") 
                  }

#fail! The mob() function still does not see my artificially created estfun().   

pid_tree <- mob(pid_formula, data = PimaIndiansDiabetes, fit = logit)
```

> Error in UseMethod("estfun") :   no applicable method for 'estfun'
>   applied to an object of class "fitdistr"   The above error message
>   does not appear when glm is used instead of fitdistr

```
# estfun runs OK outside of call to mob! 
estfun(logit(PimaIndiansDiabetes$diabetes,PimaIndiansDiabetes$glucose))
```

Answer (score 5):

In principle, it is feasible to use `mob()` for what you want to do but there is a misunderstanding of what the `estfun()` method is supposed to do and how it is being called.

`mob()` needs the following pieces of information from a model object to carry out the construction of the tree:

- The estimated parameters, typically extracted by `coef(object)`.
- The optimized objective function, typically extracted by `logLik(object)`.
- The estimating functions aka scores aka gradient contributions, typically extracted by `estfun(object)`. See `vignette("sandwich-OOP", package = "sandwich")` for an introduction.

For objects of class `"fitdistr"` the former two are available but the latter is not:

```
methods(class = "fitdistr")
## [1] coef   logLik print  vcov  
## see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Hence:

```
f <- fitdistr(x, "gamma")
coef(f)
## shape  rate 
## 5.022 0.103 
logLik(f)
## 'log Lik.' -3404 (df=2)
sandwich::estfun(f)
## Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
##   no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "fitdistr"
```

The `estfun()` function you have defined does not work for the following two reasons: (1) It is not a method `estfun.fitdistr()` that could be called by the generic function `sandwich::estfun()` that is used through the package's `NAMESPACE`. (2) It does not compute the right quantity: it's the log-likelihood but we need the derivative of the log-density with respect to both parameters and evaluated at each observation. The latter would be an n x 2 matrix.

I think it shouldn't be too hard to compute the score function of the gamma distribution by hand. But this should also be available in some R package already, possibly `gamlss.dist` or also other packages.

Comment: This is an extremely useful answer. I had no idea there was a sandwich-oop package that played such a crucial role. I'm studying that package now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. And just for the record: The package also supports an interface where the fitting function returns a list that directly contains the estimated parameters, minimized objective function, and matrix of estimating functions aka scores aka gradient contributions. But in this case the simplest solution would probably be to set up an `estfun.fitdistr()` method because everything else already works conveniently.